# convert C++ code to python code

Tags: decompilation, c++, ghidra

while I'm doing RE using ghidra i saw this code

```
  byte bVar1;
  byte bVar2;
  uint uVar3;
  
  uVar3 = 0;
  while (bVar2 = (byte)uVar3, (char)bVar2 < '\b') {
    bVar1 = *(byte *)(uVar3 + param_1) ^ *(byte *)(uVar3 + param_2);
    *(byte *)(uVar3 + param_1) = (bVar1 << (bVar2 & 7) | bVar1 >> 8 - (bVar2 & 7)) - bVar2;
    uVar3 = (uint)(byte)(bVar2 + 1);
  }
  return;
```

i know the code rotate shift but i don't think it's the same i know it's kinda diffrent here not a simple bit movement

so write a python code will make the bit-roll here make sense

Comment: FlareOn 2021 - UnlockYourFiles :)

Answer (score 1):

This code can be cleaned up to be a bit more readable

```
void __cdecl decrypt(char *dst,char *src)
{
  byte j;
  uint i;

  i = 0;
  while (j = (byte)i, (char)j < 8) {
    dst[i] = ((dst[i] ^ src[i]) << (j & 7) | (byte)(dst[i] ^ src[i]) >> 8 - (j & 7)) - j;
    i = (uint)(byte)(j + 1);
  }
  return;
}
```

But the shifting and `or`-ing still might be confusing. In this case, it's easer to look at disassembly than the decomplication and if you would do that the operations that constitutes for loop body are `xor`, `rol` and `sub`. So the shifting and `or` is pseudo-code for assembly `rol` opcode.

And it can be implemented by a simple lambda

```
rol = lambda val, r_bits, max_bits: \
    (val << r_bits%max_bits) & (2**max_bits-1) | \
    ((val & (2**max_bits-1)) >> (max_bits-(r_bits%max_bits)))
```